# Getting has no method 'writefile' even though input is a string?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var Promise = require("bluebird")
  , fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'))
  , async = require('async') 
  , program = require('commander')

program
  .version('0.0.1')
  .usage('<keywords>')
  .parse(process.argv)

async.waterfall([
  fs.readdir.bind(fs, __dirname),
  parseHTML,
], saveResult)

function parseHTML(files, callback) {
  var promises = []

  files.forEach(function (file) {
    if(file.match(/\.html$/))
      promises.push(fs.readFileAsync(file, 'utf8'))
  })

  Promise.all(promises).then(function(arr) {
    console.log(arr)
    var str = arr.join('')
    console.log(str)
    callback(null, str)
  }, function (err) {
    // error here
  })
}

function saveResult(err, result) {
  fs.writefile("untitled.html", result, function(err) {
    if (err)
      console.log(err)
    else
      console.log(result)
  })
}
```

Basically finding the HTMLs in a folder and combining them into a file.

I get this error:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'writefile'
    at saveResult (/home/alex/node/m2k/h2k.js:40:6)
    at /home/alex/node/m2k/h2k.js:33:5
```

Which I find strange since `console.log(arr)` gives an array and `console.log(str)` a string. There's no object:

```
[ '<p>File 1</p>\n', '<p>File 2</p>\n' ]
<p>File 1</p>
<p>File 2</p>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Where's `fs` defined and initialized?

Comment: @PM77-1 OK. Added full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just the casing on `fs.writeFile()` You've got all lower case when it should be camel cased.

When I make that change it works for me.

Comment: Hey, you're right. Strange, no idea how that happened. But even stranger, how did you noticed?

Comment: I've been doing some work with the fs module and made similar mistakes myself recently...more than once. So I just recognised the error.